# 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'layers'

Tags: python, keras, cleverhans

I'm trying to attack my random forest classifier.

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_features="sqrt", n_estimators=500, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, warm_start=True)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After this definition I do my predictions and after that I did the code below:

```
from keras import backend
from cleverhans.utils_keras import KerasModelWrapper
from cleverhans.attacks import FastGradientMethod
sess =  backend.get_session()

wrap = KerasModelWrapper(clf)
fgsm = FastGradientMethod(wrap, sess=sess)
fgsm_params = {'eps': 0.15,
               'clip_min': 0.,
               'clip_max': 1.}

adv_x = fgsm.generate_np(X_test, **fgsm_params) 
adv_x.shape
```

And at --> 10 **adv_x = fgsm.generate_np(X_test, **fgsm_params)** I get an attribute error.

> AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute
>   'layers'

I mean, my classifier does not have layers but how can I do this fgsm attack? Is there a way to add randomforestclassifier to sequential model to have layers? Or is there another way to attack?

Comment: I think KerasModelWrapper should get a Sequential keras model, not scikit-learn model.

Comment: @bakka I agree with you, but do you know any way to get scikit-learn model to wrapped up and act like Sequential keras model?

Comment: Good luck and have fun writing your very own keras layer: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

for code examples keras' source code for layers:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py

Comment: Is there an example specifically for a sklearn model? Random forest would be better ofc. And are you sure is there any other easier way?

Comment: @MeteHanKahraman and can I directly put RandomForest from sklearn into the build definition?

Comment: No. you can't just put 'RandomForestClassifier' from scikit-learn in there. RandomForests are trainable therefore you need to properly implement it using tensor operations.

For your non-trainable custom layers you can use Lambda layers. 

There is also this page : https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/ that is worth looking at.

Comment: I tried that too but didnt work sadly. I'll try black-box testing using cleverhans so I can keep scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier. If you answer the question I'd accept it because you still showed a way to solve the question

Comment: Blackbox testing using cleverhans seems to be the best solution. This guy made it so kudos to him: https://github.com/frankyjuang/Adversarial-Learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to run the FGSM attack on a sklearn model because CleverHans would not be able to compute the gradients needed to find the direction in which to perturb the input to find an adversarial example. To compute these gradients, a symbolic definition of the model is needed, which requires the model to be defined using TensorFlow (either directly or through a high-level abstraction like Keras).

If you'd like to use a sklearn model, you can however wrap it as a CleverHans model and use *only* **gradient-free** attacks such as SPSA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I'm also the guy at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53473184 in which I ask Random Forest (tf) with CleverHans